# Database or Filesystem for Hex files?

Tags: c#, database, filesystems

I read almost all the topics related with that and not even one is like mine problem.

I have hex files that I store in file system and I have UI that edits that files. The UI downloads all files that the user **can** edit(there are admins and users with limited access) on the local machine. Every time a users connects(with username and pass) in the UI the files that are new or edited have to be downloaded. Then he can load them, edit files if he wants and upload them on the server. I am planing to move to database because the connection and the download of every file is long, but I don't know is that a good idea. The biggest file wont be more then 0.5 MB. For now all the files are 210 MB.

Things to keep in mind:

1. Limited user access;
2. Many files edited at the same time;
3. Is it going to be faster;(for now admins it takes like 20-30 minutes to log and download all files);

   4. It's a complex structure now;(The file system folder structure is 5-6 folders deep)

So what do you think should I change from file system to database? My file system works now but it's slow. And I have problems when there is connection problem while uploading and other stuff. 
Personally I think it's good idea, but I need second opinion

Comment: If the data is truly "files" then a "file system" is pretty well suited to store and organize that data.  Why move to a database for this?  `"I have problems when there is connection problem while uploading and other stuff"` - Have you taken a look at what those problems *actually are*?  Or are you just guessing and randomly changing your design hoping that the problems will go away?

Comment: I would move to database but using file streams (no reason to keep hex raw data in a binary column). Benefit? Easier searching and you won't need to share folders. It'll be accessible in Internet/Intranet and it'll be easier to keep _history_ and locks. That said it won't speed-up your application, if each file is 0.5 MB then I don't think you need to download everything: do it on demand (maybe with a somehow smart guessing or pre-loading).

Comment: #David I am not guessing I debug the problem. 
There are some files that are edited every time someone is uploading files, and if 2 ppl uploads at the same time the file became corrupted. I made a fix but if the uploads are exactly in the same time it's problem...

That is not related with the connection but it's problem. Once that file was corrupted because the internet to the server stopped and the file didn't have the correct information.

Comment: A file that contains binary data.